# Is it possible to add a pause/delay between keystrokes when using KeePassX?

Tags: ubuntu, keepassx

I use [KeePassX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeePassX) but it sometimes happens that the Auto-Type feature isn't working. This seems to be because the keystrokes come too fast.

Now I would like to slow them down a bit, how can I do so?

I tried configuring `AutoTypeInterKeyDelay` as I read this is the property that handles that on KeePass, but it didn't work.

Preferably I would configure this for the whole application, but if need be, I would also do this for each entry.